# Difficulty sewing different cloths together in blender 2.8

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I've tried various techniques of attaching planes with different cloth physics settings together, but so far have not achieved the hoped for result.
Straight linking overwrites the settings of one sample with the other. Parenting/using hooks at most leads to a wildly extending isthmus of cloth and usually to two pieces linked by a dotted line fading into the depths of BlenderSpace.
I've even tried linking one mesh of one type to a narrow strip of another, itself linked by sewing 'threads' to the other cloth mesh set up with different settings.
Can anybody suggest a solution? Adding a thickness mod? Applying empties and hooks at every vertex? Turning back around three times and spitting?

Thanks, Quin

Comment: I'm no expert on characters or cloth at all, but I've heard this addon really helps with things like pattern making https://gumroad.com/l/GarmentTool

Comment: Thanks – sounds way more than I'm looking for, but I'm more than happy to check out new gear: you never know when it will come in useful

Comment: Downside.
gumroad.com/l/GarmentTool asks for a minimum spend of $36 and still might not do the job specified, although it looks a useful piece of kit.